# why wont the python game code let me win?

Tags: python

```
# Function showing the goal of the game and move commands
def show_instructions():
    # print a main menu and the commands
    print("Burglar Search Theme Game")
    print("Collect 8 items to win the game, or be robbed by the Stepson.")
    print("Move commands: North, South, East, West")
    print("Add to Inventory: get 'item name'")
show_instructions()

rooms = {
        'Entrance Hall': {'South': 'Den', 'North': 'Dining Room', 'West': 'Keeping Room', 'East': 'Office'},
        'Den': {'North': 'Entrance Hall', 'West': 'Sunroom', 'East': 'Home Theatre', 'item': 'Beanbag'},
        'Sunroom': {'East': 'Den', 'item': 'Sandals'},
        'Home Theatre': {'West': 'Den', 'North': 'Office', 'item': 'DVD'},
        'Keeping Room': {'North': 'Kitchen', 'East': 'Entrance Hall', 'item': 'Wine Glass'},
        'Kitchen': {'South': 'Keeping Room', 'item': 'Pot'},
        'Office': {'South': 'Home Theatre', 'North': 'Formal Parlor', 'West': 'Entrance Hall', 'item': 'Notebook'},
        'Dining Room': {'South': 'Entrance Hall', 'West': 'Garage', 'East': 'Formal Parlor', 'item': 'Chair'},
        'Garage': {'East': 'Dining Room', 'item': 'Toolbox'},
        'Formal Parlor': {'West': 'Dining Room', 'South': 'Office', 'item': 'Stepson'},
    }

current_room = 'Entrance Hall' # starts player in the Entrance Hall
inventory = [] # Adds an inventory
def get_new_room(current_room, direction):
    new_room = current_room # declares new room as current room.
    for i in rooms: # starts loop
        if i == current_room:
            if direction in rooms[i]:
                new_room = rooms[i][direction] # Assigns new room.
    return new_room #returns new room

def get_item(current_room):
    if 'item' in rooms[current_room]:
        return rooms[current_room]['item']
    else:
        return 'This room has no item!'

while (current_room): # gameplay loop
    print('You are in', current_room) # tells player what room they are in.
    print('Inventory:', inventory) # shows player their inventory
    item = get_item(current_room)  # defines item as get item
    print('You found the:', item) # tells the player what item they have found
    if item == 'Stepson' and len(inventory) != 8:
        print('The Stepson found you before you collected all the items to solve who the mystery thief was! Game over!!!')  # End of game.
        break
    direction = input('Enter direction you would like to move.') # move between rooms
    direction = direction.capitalize()

    if (direction == 'North' or direction == 'South' or direction == 'East' or direction == 'West'):
        new_room = get_new_room(current_room, direction)
        if new_room == current_room:
            print('There is no room that way, pick a different way to go!')  # Print
        else:
            current_room = new_room  # moving between rooms
    elif direction == str('get ' + item).capitalize():  # adding items
        if 'item' in inventory:
            print('This item is already in your inventory, keep searching!')  # print
        else:
            inventory.append(item)  # adding item to inventory
    else:
        print('Not a valid direction!')  # Print
    if item == 'Stepson' and len(inventory) == 8:
        print('You have found all the items and found the Stepson to be the burglar!')  # print
        break
```

This is my text-based game, everything works fine except winning the game. I can move between all rooms, collect all items but when I get to the stepson with all 8 items it doesn't say you won but if I get to the stepson without 8 items it will say I lose. please help me figure out why I cant win.

Comment: I don't follow. It looks like the code intentionally checks if you have every item before letting you win: `if item == 'Stepson' and len(inventory) == 8:` and it also checks if you meet the stepson without finding all items: `if item == 'Stepson' and len(inventory) != 8:` So what's the problem?

Comment: You are asking for the direction to move in before the line with the if condition that checks whether you have won the game. With your current code, if you find all the items, find the stepson and then move west it will say you won.

Comment: how do i get it to say you won without moving west

Comment: Move your if condition further up, before you ask the user for the next input